# different website resolution from localhost to shared host

Tags: linux, windows, localhost, screen-resolution, shared-hosting

Why is my website screen resolution in localhost is different from my shared host when display the same web page?
The webpage on shared host is 1124.17px while on localhost is 1349px.
I use the same web browser(Firefox) to display the web pages, but my localhost is in windows and shared host is in linux.
What could be the problem?
This happened when i uploaded my website to the shared host.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[The website looks like this on my localhost which is perfect resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ21y.jpg)

[But on the sharedhost it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7HCV.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Perhaps make a screen shot. Either way, maybe you have a zoom setting on one of the sites?

Comment: No i dont have zoom on neither one. Just normal display